# Closed headphones, closed, the best for like $ 175 max, which ones?

Tags: headphones, equipment, recommendations, gear

CLOSED headphones you would use when for example micing a voice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [Beyerdynamic DT770 pro 80 ohms](http://www.beyerdynamic.de/en/broadcast-studio-video-production/products/headphonesheadsets/headphones.html?tx_sbproductdatabase_pi1%5BshowUid%5D%5BshowUID%5D=44&tx_sbproductdatabase_pi1%5BshowUid%5D%5BbackPID%5D=93&cHash=cd6f9075a1), they are a safe bet.

Check out the [Sound on Sound article](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/mar99/articles/sessentials.htm) for further information.

[Beyerdynamic DT770s http://www.beyerdynamic.de/typo3temp/pics/321d688cb1.jpg](http://www.beyerdynamic.de/en/broadcast-studio-video-production/products/headphonesheadsets/headphones.html?tx_sbproductdatabase_pi1%5BshowUid%5D%5BshowUID%5D=44&tx_sbproductdatabase_pi1%5BshowUid%5D%5BbackPID%5D=93&cHash=cd6f9075a1)

Answer (score 3):

For the talent who's being mic'd or the engineer who is doing the micing?

If you want a pair of closed headphones with very little bleed to use for the vocal talent, I would most definitely go with the [Sennheiser HD280 PRO](http://www.sennheiser.co.uk/uk/home_en.nsf/root/professional_headphones-headsets_headphones_004974).  They're only $99, they have excellent isolation, for minimal bleed, and they sound fairly decent.  They take a bit of getting used to - some vocal artists think they isolate too much, so that it sounds a bit unnatural to the talent.

If you're talking about phones for an engineer, I'd go with the [Beyerdynamic DT770 PRO](http://www.beyerdynamic.de/en/broadcast-studio-video-production/products/headphonesheadsets/headphones.html?tx_sbproductdatabase_pi1%5BshowUid%5D%5BshowUID%5D=44&tx_sbproductdatabase_pi1%5BshowUid%5D%5BbackPID%5D=93&cHash=cd6f9075a1) for $199 (I'm sure you could find them somewhere for $175 or $180).  They sound amazing. The only problem is that they are high impedance, so you need a lot of power to drive them.

The DT770's are slightly hyped - if you want flat response phones for the engineer, get a pair of [Sony MDR7506s](http://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/product-MDR7506/) (the [NS10s](http://www.ns-10.net/) of headphones) or the nicer [MDR7509HD](http://pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/product-MDR7509HD/).

[Sennheiser HD280 PRO http://www.sennheiser.co.uk/sennheiser/products.nsf/resources/7FE507DDB7ABB9D9C1257482003BEA93/$File/HD_280_Pro.jpg](http://www.sennheiser.co.uk/uk/home_en.nsf/root/professional_headphones-headsets_headphones_004974)

Comment: Also, check out this great thread about headphones:

http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/61/what-are-your-favorite-headphones-and-why

Answer (score 3):

Also, check out the January issue of [Sound on Sound](http://www.soundonsound.com/) for a comparison of many studio headphones, both open and closed models.

(Digital version of the article here, you have to have a subscription or buy the article for $1,49: http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/jan10/articles/studioheadphones.htm?print=yes)

Answer (score 3):

DT770 Pro is an excellent piece of gear, you can't really go wrong with it. Bass is perhaps a bit too much, at least for accurate monitoring, but I guess you'll learn to correct it once you get used to them.

Buy the 80 ohm version, it can easily be driven by an iPod or the headphone output of a Macbook.

Comment: I own the DT770 and I liked it from the beginning. Great closed headphones. 

Answer (score 2):

Just bought the Beyerdynamic DT 770 last week. Was going to replace a lost pair of Sony's 7506 ($99), which are a staple for location sound mixers, but I was convinced to try these since they were more for studio monitoring (specifically listening to voice over recordings) and not only location sound recording. The 7506 have a slightly boosted mid range (most location sound mixers are focusing on recording dialogue out in the field, and battling other exterior sounds, so this makes sense).

The DT 770 ($179) are *supposedly* flatter, more even. I see that my info is the opposite of what other posts have said, so I guess I need to look at a frequency response chart.

I have to say, the feel so good on your head and ears. They're like sinking down into a bed full of fluffy down pillows. I could listen to Ravel all day with these headphones.

Interestingly, I didn't find the Sound on Sound article that helpful. It felt quite subjective and the details almost too application-specific, which I know is unavoidable, but rendered it un-useful for me personally. Still probably worth a read if you're shopping around.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Beyerdynamic DT250 for some years and like it, but they're worn out. I will probably go for the Sennheiser this time, seem to be durable as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think the DT770 PRO's are ok however I own a pair of [DT770 M's](http://www.beyerdynamic.de/en/broadcast-studio-video-production/products/headphonesheadsets/headphones.html?tx_sbproductdatabase_pi1%5BshowUid%5D%5BshowUID%5D=223&tx_sbproductdatabase_pi1%5BshowUid%5D%5BbackPID%5D=93&cHash=31870a78d0). The M's tended to crush my skull a little bit but they got softer with the time. I play the drums, which is why I decided to go with these rather than the 770 PRO's.

I recently used my M's for dialogue recording on a short (Loneliness Lies in Twos, I posted about it earlier today) and I could still sometimes be bothered by background noise despite the pretty good isolation (35 dBA) of the headphones. I then tried the 770 PRO's and found they isolate a lot less (18 dBA) than the M's, therefore if I had the choice between DT770 Pro's or DT770 M's for field recording, I would go for the M's for the better isolation.

[Beyerdynamic DT770 M http://www.beyerdynamic.de/typo3temp/pics/242fa81658.jpg](http://www.beyerdynamic.de/en/broadcast-studio-video-production/products/headphonesheadsets/headphones.html?tx_sbproductdatabase_pi1%5BshowUid%5D%5BshowUID%5D=223&tx_sbproductdatabase_pi1%5BshowUid%5D%5BbackPID%5D=93&cHash=31870a78d0)

Answer (score 1):

This is a no brainer the [Sony MDR7509HD](https://pro.sony/ue_US/?sonyref=pro.sony.com/bbsc/ssr/product-MDR7509HD/). Great in all sorts of settings, clean and trustworthy, well worth the price.

[image: Sony MDR7509HD]
<sub>(source: [sony.com](http://ws.sel.sony.com/PIPWebServices/RetrievePublicAsset/StepID/SEL-asset-70574/370x251))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[Sennheiser HD 25-1 II](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/507447-REG/Sennheiser_HD_25_1_II_HD_25_1_II.html) on B&H for $199.95

[alt text http://www.sennheiser.com/sennheiser/products.nsf/resources/20BEE8F4D0543C6CC1257432007FDD4A/$File/HD_25-1_II_ProductImage.jpg](http://www.sennheiser.com/sennheiser/products.nsf/resources/20BEE8F4D0543C6CC1257432007FDD4A/$File/HD_25-1_II_ProductImage.jpg)

- lightweight and comfortable
- high attenuation of background noise
- extremely robust construction